# update record right after new auto increment

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

> I have two tables as below

```
License Table(  int LID(PK)-Auto increment,
        int ProID,
        nvarchar(100) SK,
        int QTY,
        int LIS,
        int LIU
         )




Users Table(
        int UID(PK)-Auto increment,
        nvarchar(50) Username,
        int PID,
        int LID,
        nvarchar(100) SK,
        nvarchar(50) SN
        )
```

> and I have below procedure

```
procedure [dbo].[ADDUs]
(
@LID int,@username nvarchar(50),@sn nvarchar(50)
)
as
begin
INSERT INTO Users (LID, PID, SK)
SELECT LID, ProID, SK
FROM License
WHERE LID=@LID

Update Users set UserName = @username ,  sn=@sn, where LID=@LID
end
```

> The issue is everytime you run the procedure it will update the whole
>   records for users where LID=@LID and it should be where UID=@UID
>
> my question is How to modify this procedure in another way where you
>   can  update the record only for the new UID created automatically as
>   it's auto increment

Answer (score 0):

as a comment,:
 - why instead of adding second update, not put it all into same insert?:

```
    ...
    INSERT INTO Users (LID, PID, SK, Username, Sn)
    SELECT LID, ProID, SK, @username, @sn
    FROM License
    WHERE LID=@LID
    ...
```

?

- or, (not sure which sql is being used here), use SCOPE_IDENTITY() to get value of UID for last inserted row, then use it for your update

Comment: Thank you YOB, it works when I used SCOPE_IDENTITY() as below

Comment: Update Users set UserName = @username ,  sn=@sn, where 
    UID=SCOPE_IDENTITY()